# Me sale esto: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\123\determ.php on line 192"

Tags: php, javascript, phpmyadmin, login

Hice un login y todo me funcionaba a la perfeccion pero cuando hice el registro me salta ese error aqui:

```
if($contra==""){
//si que no existen ningun
//contraseña mostramos el mensaje de error
$this->Mensaje='<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button> <strong> Error!</strong> Escriba su contraseña. </div>'; 
}else{
    //Realizamos la consulta sql a la bd
    //y verificamos la contraseña
   $Contrasena = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
    $query="SELECT
            tb_login.Usuario,
            tb_login.Contra,
            tb_login.Id,
            FROM
            tb_login
            WHERE tb_login.Usuario='".$this->Usu_."'";
    //instancia de las clases
    $confi=new Datos_conexion();
    $mysql=new mysqli($confi->host(),$confi->usuario(),$confi->pasword(),$confi->DB());
    $respuesta = $mysql->query($query);//se ejecuta la consulta SQL
    //Determinamos con la instrccion if 
    //si es que la consulta nos devuelve un valor
    //mayor a cero
 if($respuesta->num_rows>0){  ***<------ES ESE EL ERROR***
               //se obtiene el arreglo de la base de datos
               $row = $respuesta->fetch_row();
```

> Soy nuevo y nunca me habia salido ese error, se los agradeceria!!

Comment: Tu consulta no está devolviendo lo que esperas, aquí: `$respuesta = $mysql->query($query);`, es posible que `$respuesta` sea `false` porque algo ha fallado. Yo cambiaría esto: `if($respuesta->num_rows>0){` por esto: **`if($respuesta){ $row = $respuesta->fetch_row(); ...`** ya que si no hay datos en la consulta, o si la consulta falla, `$respuesta` será `false`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue útil tu aporte!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al programar es importante siempre tener en cuenta lo que devuelven los objetos que estamos utilizando, para evaluarlos adecuadamente y escribir un código controlado. El Manual de PHP esa información viene siempre detallada en el apartado llamado **Valores devueltos**.

El Manual de PHP en ese apartado dice que [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php):

> Retorna `FALSE` en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo `SELECT`,
>   `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` o `EXPLAIN` es exitosa, `mysqli_query()` retornará un
>   objeto `mysqli_result`. Para otras consultas exitosas de
>   `mysqli_query()` retornará `TRUE`.

En tu caso, al no evaluar el resultado de la consulta que intentas obtener mediante el método `query` de `mysqli` obtienes este aviso:

> Trying to get property of non-object ...

Significa que `$resultado` no es un objeto `mysqli_result`, debido a que la consulta no fue exitosa y por tanto no puedes usarlo para llamar al método `num_rows`.

¿Qué falló en la consulta? La consulta tiene al menos un error de sintaxis (una coma antes del `FROM`. Pero ese no es el único fallo posible en una consulta. Por eso, cuando manejas este tipo de objetos debes escribir un código que evalúe los objetos y te diga si algo ha fallado y por qué ha fallado. Para eso, en el código que propondré habrá una variable que vaya recogiendo a lo largo del código los posibles errores.

Mysqli tiene sus limitaciones, y una de ellas es lo difícil que se hace recoger un array de datos en consultas preparadas si no tienes el driver nativo llamado `mysqlnd`. Por eso aquí se usa un función adicional `get_result` que te permitirá como suma facilidad almacenar tus resultados en un array organizado.

Por otra parte, tu código es inseguro. Siempre que intervengan datos dinámicos en la consulta debes usar consultas preparadas, ya que al permitir en la consulta datos que otros usuarios pueden escribir, podrías tener una peligrosa inyección de código. Es un riesgo de seguridad muy alto que se suele ignorar al escribir consultas SQL.

He aquí mi propuesta de código:

```
   $query="SELECT
            tb_login.Usuario,
            tb_login.Contra,
            tb_login.Id 
            FROM
            tb_login
            WHERE tb_login.Usuario=?"; //'".$this->Usu_."'"; NUNCA PONGAS DATOS DINÁMICOS DIRECTAMENTE EN UNA CONSULTA
    //instancia de las clases
    $confi=new Datos_conexion();
    $mysql=new mysqli($confi->host(),$confi->usuario(),$confi->pasword(),$confi->DB());

    if($mysql){
        $stmt=$mysql->prepare($query);

        if ($stmt){

            $stmt->bind_param("s", $this->Usu_);
            $stmt->execute();
            $arrResultado=get_result($stmt);

            if ($arrResultado){
                /*En este bloque se leerían los datos obtenidos*/
                print_r($arrResultado);                                     
            }else{
                $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"No hay datos que cumplan el criterio de la consulta");
            }

            $stmt->close();

        }else{

                $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"Hubo un fallo en la consulta ".$mysql->error);

        }
        /*Cerramos la conexión si no la vamos a usar en otras consultas*/
        $mysql->close(); 

    }else{

        $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"La conexión es nula");
    }             


  /*Evaluamos si hubo error*/
  if ($arrMensaje){

      echo $arrMensaje["mensaje"];

  }

    /*Función auxiliar*/
    function get_result( $Statement ) {
            $RESULT = array();
            $Statement->store_result();
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
                $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
                $PARAMS = array();
                while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
                    $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
                }
                call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
                $Statement->fetch();
            }
            return $RESULT;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, A. Cedano. Definitivamente era la coma(,) pero luego m alto otro error asi que opte por cambiar mi código a el que me propusiste y todo anda súper bien.
Enserio mil gracias, "you deserve the sky".

Comment: @HemersonAlvarez Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor lee: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**. Saludos.